# SPSS SMOTE (python extension) doesn't work

Tags: spss-modeler

At my work the SMOTE node is installed in SPSS Modeler. Unfortunately it doesn't do anything. When I look at the result-dataset the amount of churners/non-churners stays the same, no matter what kind of settings I choose. Do you know how to solve this? We use modeler 18.1.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked if you have the imbalanced-learn© Python library installed?

[Reference from IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3RA7_sub/modeler_mainhelp_client_ddita/clementine/python_nodes_smote.html)